# what does ^:skip-aot mean in clojure project.clj

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am new to clojure, when I use

```
lein new app
```

I saw this line

```
:main ^:skip-aot my-stuff.core
```

What does `^:skip-aot` mean?

In which section of clojure document could I find the description?

Comment: You are creating Pedestal application?

Comment: I don't know what is a Pedestal application. I just try `lein new app my-stuff` in the tutorial

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is Leiningen configuration. Have a look at : [Sample project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L177).

If you are creating a Pedestal application, then that is why they want to skip AOT:

[Why does pedestal skip AOT?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pedestal-users/RqgDJZoAip0) and in Heroku context: [Reason for skipping AOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174459/reason-for-skipping-aot)

Comment: Just adding to this answer:  In case it wasn't clear, AOT = ahead-of-time compilation (vs JIT, just-in-time compilation).  You can read more about how AOT vs JIT impacts clojure specifically in the official docs here: http://clojure.org/compilation

Comment: Another clarification, sleetdrop: Leiningen isn't really part of Clojure; it's a tool that enhances Clojure.  That's why the documentation is separate.

Comment: "It is Leiningen configuration." explains nothing.